# DefaultValidator in DynamicModel

Tags: yii2

In a Controller I use this formModel:

```
$formModel = new \yii\base\DynamicModel(['field']);
$formModel->addRule('field', 'integer',['min'=>1]);
$formModel->addRule('field', 'default',['value'=>20]);
Yii::debug("formModel:".print_r($formModel->attributes,true));
```

But the `app.log` says:

```
formModel=Array
(
    [field] => 
)
```

Why is `field` not initialized with `20`? How to use the `DefaultValidator` in a `DynamicModel`?

Comment: Default value is used when saving in DB if the field is empty. It's not initialization of field for model. `$formModel->field = 20` normally works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `yii\validators\DefaultValueValidator` is executed during the validation. Your code doesn't run validation so the `default` validation rule is never applied.

You can add the `validate()` call to your code:

```php
$formModel = new \yii\base\DynamicModel(['field']);
$formModel->addRule('field', 'integer',['min'=>1]);
$formModel->addRule('field', 'default',['value'=>20]);
$formModel->validate();
Yii::debug("formModel:".print_r($formModel->attributes,true));
```

If you want to initialize the field value without validation you can pass the init value in constructor instead:

```php
$formModel = new \yii\base\DynamicModel(['field' => 20]);
$formModel->addRule('field', 'integer',['min'=>1]);
Yii::debug("formModel:".print_r($formModel->attributes,true));
```